# Angular CLI instance service once for all component

Tags: angular-cli

I need to instance a service once for all components to avoid using this declaration in every component that need to use this service (this service is needed in almost all components)
I'm newbie in angular, I suppose there is a way to do that properly but I don't even know which term I have to search.

```
constructor(
    public paramsService: ParametersService
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for `decorators`

> https://www.tektutorialshub.com/angular/angular-decorators/

```
@yourCommonServices
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
 
  constructor() {
  }
}
```

But I do not recommend doing that, as it will add some abstraction for the futur readers / reviewers of your code.

Comment: Thanks for your rapid reply  Rapido, i'll go to check that.